# Elliptical polarisation - unsure as to what quantity is on wikipedia page

Tags: optics, notation, polarization

quick question - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_polarization - what is $\alpha_{x}$ and $\alpha_{y}$?
It's not defined on the page.
I'm asking to answer part of a question, which requires me to determine plane of polarisation of superposition of two LP waves; I'm perfectly happy with the graphical representation.

Comment: never mind, it's just the absolute phase on both components - rather than a relative phase. duh.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An oscillating function can be associated with one component of a vector which is rotating in a complex “phase space”. $e^{iθ}$ = cos(θ) + i sin(θ), where θ = ωt + ϕ. In your question, the α's correspond to θ's with different phase constants.

Comment: I answered my own question above, but have the tick anyway! I was just being stupid, as usual...